# Creating django model with foreignkey field

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    room_log = models.ForeignKey("Log", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Log(models.Model):
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=LOG_PATH)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    log = models.FileField(storage=fs, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if not os.path.exists(LOG_PATH):
            os.makedirs(LOG_PATH)
            self.log.save(self.name + '.log', ContentFile('start of log!'))
            return super(Log, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
        else:
            if not os.path.isfile(LOG_PATH + self.name + ".log"):
                self.log.save(self.name + '.log', ContentFile("start of log!"))
            else:
                pass
        return super(Log, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

I want for each Room model I create to have assigned a new Log model with the same name of the room.
I've tried editing the save() function of the Room model like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        Log.objects.create(name=self.title)
    return super(Room, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it just returns the error

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: chat_log.id
```

when creating a new Room model (The creation of Log model works great).

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you declared the `ForeignKey` as `blank=True` and `null=True`, thus if you already have a `Room` instance with an empty `ForeignKey` trying to create another with an empty `ForeignKey` will throw `UNIQUE constraint failed`.

So you need to assign to your `Room` instance a `Log` instance!

In fact in the code you provided you are not assigning any `Log` instance to your `Room` instance, you are only creating a new `Log`!

If you want to assign a `Log` when saving a `Room` change this line:

```
Log.objects.create(name=self.title)
```

to this:

```
self.room_log = Log.objects.create(name=self.title)
```

Comment: I've changed the save() function like you said and removed the blank=True, null=True from the room_log field. but now when i try to create a new Room model I have to assign an existing Log model for saving the Room model. How would i do it?

Comment: @AmitGrossberg look at marin answer too, He is right that you forget to give the Log model models.Model

Comment: In the admin page - when creating a new room model and not specifying a log model I just can't click on the save button, the room_log field is required.

Comment: @AmitGrossberg You can keep the blank=True, null=True if you want but the problem is that you can't have multiple blank ForeignKey cause it will throw the UNIQUE constraint failed!

Comment: @AmitGrossberg ensure that you run the proper migrations after reimplementing null=True and blank=True

Comment: I'm sorry for asking for so much questions, but I just don't know hot the pass the UNIQUE constraint failed error, what would i need to do (code wise)?

Comment: If you keep the blank=True and null=True in the admin you are not able to save the model Room without giving a Log instance?

Comment: Nope, it Returns "UNIQUE constraint failed: chat_log.id" as before, I also made sure I have the right migrations

Comment: where chat_log field is declared?

Comment: nowhere, that's really weird, I searched it in my whole project and I don't have something like that, I also redid the migrations (deleted and re-migrate, with a new DB, and I still get this error.

Comment: I can't debug your code cause i don't have it but i'm sure that somewhere there is this field declared, cause deleting all migrations file and using a new db didn't solve the problem as you said! If you didn't make sure that you deleted all migrations files (like 0001_initial ecc), delete the db and recreate it and do makemigrations and then migrate!